# order by Name(auto number) doesn't work as expected apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I created a custom object and use `Name` field as a `autonumber` type, `TA - {0000}` is the format of it.

There are some sample data:

`TA - 666
TA - 777
TA - 888
TA - 999
TA - 1000`


When I query this object `order by Name desc`, it returned like below:

`TA - 999
TA - 888
TA - 777
TA - 666
TA - 1000`


That's not I expected, who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it created 3-digit numbers then it means your autonumber format was originally `TA - {000}` or even `TA - {0}`. Values "spill over" once they reach the format's max so it then continues to 1000, 1001 rather than looping the counter back to 0.

So whoever created the field initially didn't plan ahead.

What you can do is to try to fix the data.

1. First try it in a sandbox rather than straight in production
2. Announce that you're going to mess around a lot and nobody should create any new records on this object until you're done. If needed - lock people out by mass freezing their user accounts or revoking the "Create" right on the Profiles...
3. Attempt to change the field's type from autonumber to text. If the field is referenced in any code - you'll have to temporarily comment it out.
4. Run a data fix - for example export it all, fix in excel, import update back. Whatever works for you. Pray you don't hit any validation rules (might have to temp disable some?)
5. Flip the field back to autonumber, this time picking long enough format string. You'll be given an option to specify counter's initial value.
6. Try it out, make a new record. If all works fine - delete that record and reset the counter again.
7. Undo whatever you've changed in validation rules, apex etc.
8. Unlock users